# RemoteApps with Win2K8 R2 STD and Mac users

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx, remote-desktop, rdp, remoteapp

I am using Win2K8 R2 and have enabled RemoteApps. I can connected to the RemoteApp (Outlook) without any trouble from another Windows based PC, however Mac clients, using the latest RDP client can not.  The error they receive is the following:

"You were disconnected from the Windows-based computer because of problems during the licensing protocal."

Any ideas how to resolve this? I am also using the "120-day grace period".. not sure if that matters..

Answer (score 2):

I had the Mac user delete the contents of:
/users/Shared/Microsoft/RDC Crucial Server Information/

That seems to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for remoteapps WS2008 http://www.thinomenon.com/downloads/thinrdc-0.2.8.rar this cliente work fine